# Security when compiling custom language to Java

Tags: java, security, reflection, sandbox

I'm compiling user-inputted code in a custom language to Java. The resulting code, as of now, can only have one class with static methods. Because the user code is insecure, I've set up a security manager and I've restricted file, network, and many other permissions. The code is also being run on a sandboxed virtual machine.

What else can I do to ensure the machine will not be compromised. Specifically, given all the rumblings about Java insecurity, are there test packages or suites that I can use to try to break out of the Java sandbox into the VM itself?